# change color of javascript sentence

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in javaScript, and it works fine.
But I need to know how can I change the appearance color to red or any other color besides black.
I'd appreciate if someone can help me.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d= new Date
    document.writeln("Time is: " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes())
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the text in a span with red color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    document.writeln("<span style='color:red'>Time is: " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + '</span>')
</script>
```

Comment: Simulpost with near-identical answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var s = "<span style='color:red'>Time is: " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + "</span>";
    document.writeln(s);
</script>
```

Comment: `new Date` should be `new Date()` I think.

Comment: @Andy Optional. Although I'd recommend including the `()`

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to put your code inside any (e.g. DIV) HTML element and style that element.

```
"<div style='background-color:#003366'>YOUR TEXT</div>"
```

don't forget that javascript is only something like "a  dynamic HTML support"... you usually  don't use `.writeln()` in the code. more like

`document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "myBriliantText";`